# ScrollTop duration not respected by script

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop, duration

I have a bug in my code.

My scrollTop is working but not the duration effect of it.

Clicking on scroll link does trigger the change of offset, but it's done instantly instead of with the duration of 1000 I gave it.

thanks a lot for future help,
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<body class="demo-2">

    <main>
        <header class="codrops-header"> 
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center;">Votre Fleuriste à Montmartre</h1>
            </div>              
        </header>
        <!-- Initial markup -->
        <div class="segmenter" style="background-image: url(img/MUSE-01-BIS1.jpg)">             
        </div>

        <h2 class="trigger-headline trigger-headline--hidden"><span>m</span><span>u</span><span>s</span><span>e</span></h2>
        <div class="bottom-nav">
            <button class="btn btn--trigger">Voir plus</button>
        </div>

        <div class="scroll-to scroll-hidden">

        </div>

        <div class="infos infos-hidden" id="infos"> 

            <div class="infos-container">

            </div>
        </div>

    </main>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
            header = document.querySelector('.codrops-header'),
            infos = document.querySelector('.infos'),
            scroll = document.querySelector('.scroll-to'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {
                pieces: 4,
                animation: {
                    duration: 1500,
                    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
                    delay: 100,
                    translateZ: 100
                },
                parallax: true,
                positions: [
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 45, height: 45},
                    {top: 55, left: 0, width: 45, height: 45},
                    {top: 0, left: 55, width: 45, height: 45},
                    {top: 55, left: 55, width: 45, height: 45}
                ],
                onReady: function() {
                    trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
                    trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        segmenter.animate();
                        headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                        header.classList.add('hidden-header');
                        scroll.classList.remove('scroll-hidden');
                        $('.scroll-to').html('<a href="#infos">Scroll</a>');
                        infos.classList.remove('infos-hidden');
                        infos.classList.add('infos-flex');
                        header.classList.remove('codrops-header');
                        this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
                    });
                }
            });


        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
    }); 

    </script>

    <script>

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, my all item:

```
scrollToWeb: function()
{
    var objectScroll = $(".scrollToWeb");

    if(objectScroll.length <= 0) return false;

    $(".scrollToWeb").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var objectHref = $(this).attr("href").replace(strHOST , ''),
            objectId = $(this).attr("id");

        if( $('#'+objectId).length <= 0) return true;

        $('#'+objectId).addClass('active');

        var target = objectHref,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1500, 'swing');
    });
}
```